# Nonzero-Exit Compiler Hint

Tags: c++, c, compiler-warnings

TL;DR: I want

```
int some_opaque_error_handler() __attribute__((returns_nonzero));
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ equivalent of this
```

---

A C/C++-based library I use uses return-codes to indicate errors, which causes the compiler to complain about using "unitialized" values. For example

```c
int foo(int **ptr)
{
  // detail not important here, just that:
  // 1. compiler sees the contents of foo() from bar()
  // 2. foo() has some kind of early return in error-path
  // 3. precise return value of foo() from early return not known to the compiler
  // 4. ptr is 100% properly initialized in non-error path (i.e. warning is 
  //    indeed spurious)
  if (ptr == 0xdeadbeef) {
    return some_opaque_error_handler(...); // returns nonzero
  }
  *ptr = properly_initialize();
  return 0;
}

int bar()
{
  int *p;

  if (foo(&p)) {
    return /* continue propogating the error yadda yadda yadda */;
  }
  *p += 1; // Warning: p may be used uninitialized
}
```

In this case `*p` is never accessed from `bar()` if `foo()` returns an error, but since the error handler is opaque the compiler cannot know this.

Is there anyway to let the compiler know that returning via error handler is *almost always*<sup>[1]</sup>  nonzero (and hence any subsequent accesses never occur?)<sup>[2]</sup>. I have similar issues running static analyzers, since they too assume that execution may continue past such points.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Users may change the behavior of the error handler to -- as unlikely as it may be -- return `0` so any solution/compiler hint must be nonbinding.

<sup>[2]</sup> Yes I know I can simply initialize the variables (**which is what I currently do**) but:

1. There are a metric boatload of such cases
2. These warnings seem to be heavily dependent on compiler, compiler version, optimization level, and orientation of Saturns rings with respect to the galactic plane

So this feels like an unwinnable game of whack-a-mole

Comment: I don’t have a real solution (I run into the same problem in my code) but one work-around would be to declare a type with a default constructor instead of a plain int, and pass in a pointer to that instead.

Comment: *"I know I can simply initialize the variables but"* Still, this is what I would do.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Given they want this to work in C, not just C++, that's not a viable option. Just initialize the variables.

Comment: Please post a compilable full MCVE with all functions declarations and compiler and compiler version and compiler options that you are using for getting the warning.

Comment: Are you going to modify the third party code? Or are you asking about how to address your code that is using a third party library?

Comment: > Are you going to modify the third party code? Or are you asking about how to address your code that is using a third party library? @jxh I am writing the library code in question, so modifying the library code.

Comment: This is a case where functional programming makes things more clear. Allow your function to return the new value. Allow your function to use an out parameter to represent the error code.

Comment: > Allow your function to use an out parameter to represent the error code. @jxh This would require rewriting hundreds of thousands of lines (the error handling should be uniform across the library) so somewhat infeasible I'm afraid...

Comment: @ShadowRanger I interpreted the presence of both `c` and `c++` tags to indicate that they were calling a C API from a C++ application.

Comment: @Neil I don't see how this solves the problem. Assuming you mean doing this in `foo()` this would still mean `ptr` is "used unitialized" in `bar()` since the whole point is that the compiler assumes execution continues after the call to `foo()` is made.

Comment: You're saying that if someone should change the code so that `some_opaque_error_handler()` returns zero, you want the code to still work, and that's why `__builtin_unreachable()` is unacceptable?  But if someone does that, then `bar()` really will use `p` uninitialized and the code breaks anyway.  Frankly I would be more inclined to wrap `some_opaque_error_handler()` to follow it with an `assert(retval != 0)` so that you get an immediate and visible failure if someone bungles it in that way.  And that will fix your warning too.

Comment: On the other side of things, if you arrange it so that `foo` is also opaque (move to another translation unit, use `__attribute__((noipa))`, etc), then I expect the compiler will assume that `foo(&p)` always initializes `p`, and that will silence your warning too.

Comment: > You're saying that if someone ... still work @NateEldredge yes. Users are able to register their own error handler which runs as part of `some_opaque_error_handler()` where they are allowed to ignore/reset the error -- footgun or not. Changing this to disallow it would break a great deal of dependent code. Moving things to another TU works only so long as you don't get a similar situation within the new TU :(. I will look into `__attribute__((noipa))` though, I was not aware of it.

Comment: I still don't get it.  If overriding `some_opaque_error_handler()` to return 0 is already going to make everything break, then why do you object to solutions that will simply make it break in a different (and IMHO preferable) fashion?  Or if such an override actually needs to be supported, then your code for `bar()` really is incorrect, and the warning is entirely legitimate and should be heeded.

Comment: If you want the hint to be non-binding, then does that mean if the code path did in fact cause the uninitialized pointer to be dereferenced, you would really want the static analysis to really pick it up in those cases?

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not here to debate the constraints. I absolutely agree with you that giving the user the ability to ignore errors in this fashion was a misstep, but it has been this way for 20 years and I have verifiable cases of users depending on this behavior. Changing it is not within the purview of this question.

Comment: @jxh perfect world I would want the hint to be binding _only for the static analyzer_. That is, the static analyzer really should just assume that `some_opaque_error_handler()` always returns nonzero.

Comment: So just so that I understand - in case the user has overridden the error handler to return 0, your *desired* outcome for the example function `bar` is that it should *actually* dereference the uninitialized pointer `p`, thus causing a crash or data corruption or whatever else, and *not* cause a compiler warning nor abort in any other fashion.

Comment: @NateEldredge That is correct. > and not cause a compiler warning nor abort in any other fashion. Assuming the compiler is somehow able to prove that the error is gobbled and `0` is returned from the error handler, it ideally can (read: _should_) emit warnings, but the error handling process itself can neither crash nor abort the program. This allows users to recover from "soft" errors such as limited memory etc. I do want to stress that the vast majority of use-cases (and in fact the recommended usage) is not to gobble errors, hence why I consider the "use uninitialized" warnings as spurious.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand now.  Is it an option to use different versions of the code for static analysis versus for release build, via `#ifdef` or the like?  You could build the analysis version with a `__builtin_unreachable()` as in KamilCuk's answer so as to suppress warnings in the case where zero is returned.  And then for the release version, the code allows for a zero return, and you either disable uninitialized warnings across the board, or just ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a macro, you can hack your function to look like this:

```
#define some_opaque_error_handler(...) \
        (some_opaque_error_handler(__VA_ARGS__) ?: -1)
```

This relies on a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) where leaving out the middle operand gives the tested value if it is non-zero.

---

If you want to avoid using an extension, you can embed the logic into an inlined function.

```
static inline int return_nonzero (int exp) {
    return (exp ? exp : -1);
}
/* ... */
#define some_opaque_error_handler(...) \
        return_nonzero(some_opaque_error_handler(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Comment: Hmmm would this still work if the user decides to gobble the error (i.e. return `0`)? I suppose I can make the `-1` some random magic number and test for that to detect this to reduce the likelihood of conflicting with a user error code. Thanks for the tip

Comment: You can set a flag in a (thread specific) global to indicate if the error handler was trying to return 0 or not.

Answer (score 0):

Mark the function as accessing for write.

```
__attribute__((__access__(__write_only__, 1)))
int foo(int **ptr) {
```

> I want `int some_opaque_error_handler() __attribute__((returns_nonzero));`

You would do this:

```
#define some_opaque_error_handler()  \
   __extension__({ \
     int _x = some_opaque_error_handler(); \
     if (_x == 0) __builtin_unreachable(); \
     _x; \
  })
```

or the same on calling site.

Comment: Users may change the behavior of the error handler and -- however unlikely it may be -- return 0 from it so I cannot use `__builtin_unreachable()`. That is, I need the "nonzero return" to ideally be a nonbinding contract.

Comment: I do not understand a "nonbinding contract". That's not a contract ;) You can do the same on the calling site.

Comment: More like an agreement then ... i.e. something that behaves like a `__attribute__((unused))` which silences warnings about a variable being unused but does not lead to additional warnings/errors if the variable turns out to be used after all

Comment: On the calling site `#define foo(x)  __extension__({ int _y = foo(x); if (_y == 0) { *x = NULL; __builtin_unreachable(); } _y; })`

Comment: 1. There are hundreds of such functions so wrapping each and every one of them -- and handling each arguments initialization -- is not feasible. 2.  I would like to avoid using extensions that I cannot transparently hide (like attributes).